# Where to save a file in an application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've made a web app with a lot of images. Safaris memory can't open all of those. So I build an application that stores the images on the iPad.
However, they can change dynamically and I don't know where I can save the files. The rest of the code works with a file where I put some images.

**Notice:** On the Simulator (iPad) it works normally, but on the real device I have a permission problem.

This is my code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://link_of_my_image", [splitLink objectAtIndex: 1],[splitLink objectAtIndex: 3] ] ]]];
            
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
            
BOOL test10 = [data1 writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@/folder/%@",linkSlidesFile, [splitLink objectAtIndex: 1],[splitLink objectAtIndex: 3]] atomically:YES];
            
NSLog(@"creat Image --------------------- %@ %i",
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@/folder/%@",[splitLink objectAtIndex: 0], [splitLink objectAtIndex: 1],[splitLink objectAtIndex: 3]], test10);
```

Log Simulator :

```
creat Image --------------------- Link_of_image_ipad 1
```

Log Ipad :

```
creat Image --------------------- Link_of_image_ipad 0
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You may want to look at storing the image data in CoreData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to write to the Documents directory; add this method to your class in order to get its path:

```
+ (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this similar response everywhere, but I can't seem to get it to work right.  Whenever the app closes and reopens, the path is different because of the GUID in the file path. (Example:   /var/mobile/Applications/96553886-38FC-4963-ADC8-96F8FBE9384C/Documents/fileToSave.txt).  Is the above solution only for writing to a file and reading from it in the same session, or will it persist?  If not, how can you get the path to stay static?